# An alternative way to skeletonize in OpenCV Python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, signal-processing, feature-detection

I'm trying to skeletonize the features below, in order to extract information about 1) the length of the features 2) the curvature of the features. I came across this [skeletonization approach](http://opencvpython.blogspot.com/2012/05/skeletonization-using-opencv-python.html), which iteratively erodes and erodes the image. Shown below is the result - which looks awful. Can some one recommend a different approach to skeletonizing my features?

[image][image]

Here's the example from the link above:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('sofsk.png',0)
size = np.size(img)
skel = np.zeros(img.shape,np.uint8)

ret,img = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,0)
element = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS,(3,3))
done = False

while( not done):
    eroded = cv2.erode(img,element)
    temp = cv2.dilate(eroded,element)
    temp = cv2.subtract(img,temp)
    skel = cv2.bitwise_or(skel,temp)
    img = eroded.copy()

    zeros = size - cv2.countNonZero(img)
    if zeros==size:
        done = True

cv2.imshow("skel",skel)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I think you should invert the image, because your features are the black regions. The object you need skeletonized has to be white.